# Errors in iosfwd

Tags: c++, std, keil

I´m not sure if this is enough information, but I keep getting an error in the `iosfwd` file, which is from the standard library.

I would post code where I included it, but I don´t think that I did.

It keeps saying `error 65 expected a ;` on multiple lines. The lines are all similar to: `typedef basic_fstream<char> fstream;`.

I am at a complete loss because I am sure that a file in the standard library does not have an error and I do have a semi-colon so why does it say it expects one?

I am using keil v5.

Comment: The standard has no file named `iosfwd.h` but a header called `iosfwd` are you meaning that? It seems your compiler is prestandard, or the file you are mentioning doesn't even belong to it.

Comment: What did you do *before including the standard header*? That should be the actual source of your troubles.

Comment: that´s the thing, I don´t think I ever included it.  It is in Keil´s include folder, does it automatically include those files?

Comment: Yes, it automatically includes them. Are you doing something in your code before including any header file into your program?

Comment: Even if you didn't include it, it's possible that a standard header that you did include included it at the top.

Comment: well i am also having a problem with rw/_defs.h which is automatically included. When I search my project for rw/_defs.h it shows the code in the folder for keil where those include files are. But when I search for iosfwd it does not show anything, which makes me think it is not even part of my project.

Comment: But no I am not doing anything before I include my header files.